# Error:java: invalid flag: --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED

Tags: java, javafx, invalid-argument

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'WarrantySystem'
Information:javac 1.8.0_201 was used to compile java sources
Information:2/21/2019 6:16 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1 s 846 ms
Error:java: invalid flag: --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: it will be really helpful if you can add your code which you think related to the error :)

Comment: You're using a java version (8) where modules (and therefore the `--add-exports` command line parameter) have not been introduced. It shouldn't be surprising `javac` has issues when parsing that parameter.

Comment: Expanding on what fabian said, it wasn't until Java 9 that modules, and thus `--add-exports`, were added. However, Java 9 and 10 are EOL. Latest release is Java 11. Either upgrade Java or remove any module related options.